# Notify the user on Facebook at some time

Tags: facebook

Let's say I have a Facebook application which is monitoring friends birthdays. I want to notify the user that her friend will have a birthday in next two days. The first part is only cron which will check the dates, but is there any way how to notify the user? I didn't found anything for this. It was there a year ago but all of the API changes it looks like the removed all offline messages. I don't want to send an email to the user, it will be much more better to stay with everything on Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain an [offline access](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) permission and then use [counters](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas) to notify the user

Comment: Offline access permission has been deprecated as of today.:)

Answer (score 0):

The app-generated notifications are still possible. See this doc:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464